# React Native Loading Data Outside of Constructor

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm just getting the hang of react-native but really getting stuck on Scenario #2 and #3.  It might be the lateness of the hour, but I can't just get the listview to repopulate outside of the scene's constructor...

**Note: this is a simple example that will eventually become a more advanced data load**

**Scenario #1 Bind in controller**

This works great:

```
export default class HomeView extends Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource(
      {
        rowHasChanged: (r1,r2) => r1 !== r2
      }
    );

    var data = [
        {"id":1, "desc": "Some description of a request", "group": "Today"},
        {"id":2, "desc": "Another description of a request", "group": "Today"} 
      ];

    this.state = {
      loaded: false,
      data: data,
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data)
    };
```

**Scenario #2 - Call load method**

This subset starts from the constructor.  When I call the method directly, it yields the "Calling setState on an unmounted component is a problem" error.  Fair enough, but it does all the method and run the two console statements.  I tried to resolve this in #3.

```
    var data = [
        {"id":1, "desc": "Some description of a request", "group": "Today"},
        {"id":2, "desc": "Another description of a request", "group": "Today"} 
      ];

    this.state = {
      loaded: false,
      data: data,
      dataSource: ds
    };

     console.log("About to load data");
     this.loadData();
   } //end ctor

   loadData() {
     console.log("Data count is: " + this.state.data.length);

     this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.data),
        loaded     : true
     });
   }
```

**Scenario #3 - Using Bind**

Using the Bind() method for LoadData just leaves blank screen without the logging statements from appearing, so it's hosed in another way.  Code starts from within constructor...

```
 var data = [
    {"id":1, "desc": "Some description of a request", "group": "Today"},
    {"id":2, "desc": "Another description of a request", "group": "Today"} 
  ];

 this.state = {
   loaded: false,
   data: data,
   dataSource: ds
 };

  console.log("About to load data");
   this.loadData = this.loadData.bind(this);
} //end ctor

loadData() {
   console.log("Data count is: " + this.state.data.length);

   this.setState({
     dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.data),
     loaded     : true
   });
}
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: Why don't you want to use scenario 1?

Comment: You can also get the same behavior, by calling your loadData() method in componentWillMount() function.

Comment: @coderhacker because it will eventually become an Ajax request or local storage data load and I don't want all my logic to be in the constructor...  I'm using es6 classes and it appears componentDidMount is not a supported API method...

Comment: Actually it does appear componentWillMount and componentDidMount are valid and using componentDidMount (since it said I was performing an action on an unmounted component, and componentDidMount runs after mounting) solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

use const keyword and declare the outside of the class

```
const data = [
        {"id":1, "desc": "Some description of a request", "group": "Today"},
        {"id":2, "desc": "Another description of a request", "group": "Today"} 
      ];
```

Comment: It won't always be static data though - that was just a quick way to provide a sample for what will eventually become a more complicated scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I tried it earlier but apparently I didn't  use it correctly.  The scene has a few built-in methods that are usable: `componentWillMount()` runs before the `render()` method is called, before the component is mounted, and `componentDidMount()` runs after render() and after mounting, so doing this in `componentDidMount()` now works:

```
componentDidMount() {
    var data = [
        {"id":1, "desc": "Some description of a request", "group": "Today"},
        {"id":2, "desc": "Another description of a request", "group": "Today"} 
      ];

    console.log("Loading data...");

    this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(data),
        loaded     : true
    });
  }
```